# Trying to send an image to a Browser but its not working ... :/

Tags: c#

I have the problem that i can't send an image to the browser. After reading endless comments i decided to ask by myself. I send the Content-type and a bmp as byte[] but it is never showing an image in the browser.

Thanks for your help :D

I tried to use ASCII encoding to send the image but nope.

```
private const string headerImage = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type:        
                            image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: %bytes%\r\n\r\n";

...
g.CopyFromScreen(Cursor.Position.X - 100, Cursor.Position.Y - 100, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
stream = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(stream, bmp.RawFormat);
byte[] img = stream.ToArray();
POST(headerImage.Replace("%bytes%", img.Length + "") + img, nwStream);
...

private void POST(String msg, NetworkStream nwStream)
{
   UTF8Encoding uft8 = new UTF8Encoding();
   byte[] send = uft8.GetBytes(msg);
   nwStream.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
}
```

Just the console "TypeError: image is null"

Comment: Why are you trying to convert an image to a string?  An image is an image, not a string.  Send the image as it is, as a byte array.  Also, I'm pretty sure the code you have won't compile.

Comment: There's so much wrong with this code. For example, if `+ img` actually compiles, it will call `.ToString()` on `byte[] img`, which will give you `"System.Byte[]"`. Worse still, you're trying to convert binary data to a string, which is pretty much universally a no-no: text encoding is intended for text and can't represent all binary data correctly (i.e. byte[] -> string -> byte[] won't necessarily give the same byte array).

Comment: OMG i forgot that the POST methotd only takes strings. Thank you so much. and @Luke the code compiled :P

Comment: I'm not really sure how you came to that (incorrect) conclusion from the advice given above, but the lesson to be learnt here is that concatenating a string with anything other than a string (even if it compiles, it never used to) is bad!